How to customize the message for inactive user in Djoser?
I am working on a Django project and I am using Djoser as my auth library. However, when a user is trying to create a jwt token it returns
{
    "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
}

for when there is no user with the credentials and when there is a user who is inactive. After some research, I found the piece of code below that was used to override the TokenObtain in the simplejwt library, which Djoser was written on top of, but I don't know how to actually go about it. I am fairly new to Djoser.
from rest_framework import status, exceptions
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenObtainSerializer


class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenObtainSerializer):
    
  
    # Overiding validate function in the TokenObtainSerializer  
    def validate(self, attrs):
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            'password': attrs['password'],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs['request'] = self.context['request']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        # print(f"\nthis is the user of authenticate_kwargs {authenticate_kwargs['email']}\n")
       
        
        '''
        Checking if the user exists by getting the email(username field) from authentication_kwargs.
        If the user exists we check if the user account is active.
        If the user account is not active we raise the exception and pass the message. 
        Thus stopping the user from getting authenticated altogether. 
        
        And if the user does not exist at all we raise an exception with a different error message.
        Thus stopping the execution righ there.  
        '''
        try:
         user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=authenticate_kwargs['email'])
         if not user.is_active:
             self.error_messages['no_active_account']=_(
                 'The account is inactive'
             )
             raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                 self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                 'no_active_account',
             )
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
          self.error_messages['no_active_account'] =_(
              'Account does not exist')
          raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
              self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
              'no_active_account',
          )
          
        '''
        We come here if everything above goes well.
        Here we authenticate the user.
        The authenticate function return None if the credentials do not match 
        or the user account is inactive. However here we can safely raise the exception
        that the credentials did not match as we do all the checks above this point.
        '''
        
        self.user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
        if self.user is None:
            self.error_messages['no_active_account'] = _(
                'Credentials did not match')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                'no_active_account',
            )
        return super().validate(attrs)


Add a [mre] of what YOU are doing then we can take it up from there.

To customize this error, you need to override the SimpleJWT serializer. For this, you should also override the urls.py and view.py
In the view, you can inherit from TokenObtainPairView and add your serizlier:
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
class YourCustomLoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer

In the serializer, you should inherit from TokenObtainPairSerializer:
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
     ...

Now you have 2 options to override the error message (there are other alternatives available, but these two are sufficient):

You can override the class variable default_error_messages like this:

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenObtainSerializer):
     default_error_messages = {
        "no_active_account": "your error msg"
    }


Override the validate method to handle validation errors yourself:


from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    _User = get_user_model()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username_field = self._User.USERNAME_FIELD
        user = self._User.objects.filter(email=attrs[username_field]).first()
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed({"error": "your error msg"})
        if not user.is_active:                
            raise AuthenticationFailed({"error": "your error msg"})

        authenticate_kwargs = {
            username_field: attrs[username_field],
            "password": attrs["password"],
        }
        user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed({"error": "your error msg"})
        return super().validate(attrs)


Also, I suggest looking at serializers TokenObtainPairSerializer and TokenObtainSerializer for a better understanding.

Here's an example:
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer    
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        User = get_user_model()
        username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD
        user = User.objects.filter(email=attrs[username_field]).first()
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(
                "Email or password is incorrect.",  # message
                "no_active_account",  # code used by djoser
            )
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(
                "Please activate your account first",
                "no_active_account",
            )
        return super().validate(attrs)

